# 500 Internal Server Error page in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, error-handling, custom-errors

I'm trying to set up custom errors for an MVC site. I have the 404 page working fine, but when testing a server error I get the default message:

> Sorry, an error occurred while processing your request.

Instead of my custom page.

I have set this up in the web.config:

```
<customErrors mode="On"  defaultRedirect="~/Error/500">
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Error/404" />
    <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/Error/500" />
</customErrors>
```

My error controller is as follows:

```
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
    [ActionName("404")]
    public ActionResult NotFound()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [ActionName("500")]
    public ActionResult ServerError()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

I'm testing the `500` error page by throwing an exception in one of my views:

```
[ActionName("contact-us")]
public ActionResult ContactUs()
{
    throw new DivideByZeroException();
    return View();
}
```

Why is it that only 404 errors are handled? How can I display the error page for `500` errors?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Figured this out..

It was some boilerplate code left in the `Global.asax.cs` when creating the project:

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
   filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
}
```

In particular:

```
filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
```

This creates an new instance of `HandleErrorAttribute` which is applied Globally to all of my views.

With no customization, if a view throws an error while utilizing this attribute, MVC will display the default `Error.cshtml` file in the `Shared` folder which is where the: `"Sorry, an error occurred while processing your request."` came from.

From the documentation on [HandleErrorAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.handleerrorattribute%28v=vs.108%29.aspx):

> By default, when an action method with the HandleErrorAttribute attribute throws any exception, MVC displays the Error view that is located in the ~/Views/Shared folder.

Commenting this line out solved the problem and allowed me to use custom error pages for 500 errors.

Comment: In MVC5, global filter registration is done by FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilter(GlobalFilters.Filters) in Global.asax.cs, so for anyone looking to use this fix in MVC 5, it may be this line you need to look for